# Slight undesired transparency from FillRectangle

Tags: c++, winapi, graphics, gdi+

I have a window created with the `WS_EX_LAYERED` window style. I am currently drawing onto a memory bitmap using GDI+, and using [`UpdateLayeredWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633556%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to update the graphical content of my layered window.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```cpp
void Redraw(HWND hWnd, int width, int height) {
    static bool floppy = true;

    floppy = !floppy;

    HDC hScreenDC = GetDC(HWND_DESKTOP);
    HDC hMemDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hScreenDC);
    HBITMAP hBmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hScreenDC, width, height);
    HGDIOBJ hObj = SelectObject(hMemDC, hBmp);

    Graphics gfx(hMemDC);

    SolidBrush b(Color(254, (floppy ? 255 : 0), (floppy ? 0 : 255), 0));
    gfx.FillRectangle(&b, Rect(0, 0, width, height));

    BLENDFUNCTION blend;
    blend.BlendOp = AC_SRC_OVER;
    blend.BlendFlags = 0;
    blend.SourceConstantAlpha = 255;
    blend.AlphaFormat = AC_SRC_ALPHA;

    POINT src = { 0, 0 };

    SIZE size;
    size.cx = width;
    size.cy = height;

    Assert(UpdateLayeredWindow(
        hWnd,
        hScreenDC,
        NULL,
        &size,
        hMemDC,
        &src,
        RGB(0, 0, 0),
        &blend,
        ULW_ALPHA
    ));

    SelectObject(hMemDC, hObj);
    DeleteObject(hBmp);
    DeleteDC(hMemDC);
    ReleaseDC(HWND_DESKTOP, hScreenDC);
}
```

When creating my `SolidBrush`, I specified the value of 254 for the alpha component. This results in a 99.6% opaque fill, which is not what I want.

When I specify 255 as the alpha component, there appears to be no fill; my window becomes completely transparent. This is an issue because I wish to draw shapes that are 100% opaque, but I also wish to draw some that aren't.

Comment: Just a comment to this old post, you are mixing GDI and GDI+ too much, GDI should only be needed to BitBlt the bitmap to screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be some qwerks with `FillRectangle`. This becomes apparent when we observe that using `FillEllipse` with a `SolidBrush` whose alpha component is 255, results in the shape being rendered perfectly (opaque).

Here are two work-arounds that I came up with, which each solve the issue for me:

- **Call** `FillRectangle` **twice**

  ```cpp
  SolidBrush b(Color(254, 255, 0, 0));
  gfx.FillRectangle(&b, Rect(0, 0, width, height));
  gfx.FillRectangle(&b, Rect(0, 0, width, height));
  ```

  Since the same area is being filled twice, they will blend and create RGB(255, 0, 0) regardless of the content behind the window (it's now 100% opaque). I do not prefer this method, as it requires every rectangle to be drawn twice.
- **Use** [`FillPolygon`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms535770%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) **instead**

  Just as with `FillEllipse`, `FillPolygon` doesn't seem to have the colour issue, **unless you call it like so**:

  ```
  SolidBrush b(Color(255, 255, 0, 0));
  Point points[4];
  points[0] = Point(0, 0);
  points[1] = Point(width, 0);
  points[2] = Point(width, height);
  points[4] = Point(0, height);
  gfx.FillPolygon(&b, points, 4); //don't copy and paste - this won't work
  ```

  The above code will result in a 100% transparent window. I am guessing that this is either due to some form of optimisation that passes the call to `FillRectangle` instead. Or - most likely - there is some problem with `FillPolygon`, which is called by `FillRectangle`. However, if you add an extra `Point` to the array, you can get around it:

  ```
  SolidBrush b(Color(255, 255, 0, 0));
  Point points[5];
  points[0] = Point(0, 0);
  points[1] = Point(0, 0); //<-
  points[2] = Point(width, 0);
  points[3] = Point(width, height);
  points[4] = Point(0, height);
  gfx.FillPolygon(&b, points, 5);
  ```

  The above code will indeed draw a 100% opaque shape, which fixes my problem.

Answer (score 1):

`UpdateLayeredWindow()` requires a bitmap with pre-multiplied alpha:

> Note that the APIs use premultiplied alpha, which means that the red,
>   green and blue channel values in the bitmap must be premultiplied with
>   the alpha channel value. For example, if the alpha channel value is x,
>   the red, green and blue channels must be multiplied by x and divided
>   by 0xff prior to the call.

You can use [`Bitmap::ConvertFormat()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms536306%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to convert a bitmap to pre-multiplied (the format is `PixelFormat32bppPARGB`).

Comment: This appears to have removed all (real) transparency. Using a `SolidBrush` of ARGB: [ 128, 255, 0, 0 ], the drawn colour is actually RGB: [ 128, 0, 0 ]. Also, congratulations on 10k.

Comment: Hmm, to be honest I'm not sure why that would be. I haven't ever tried to use GDI+ in this way myself. I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14315869/drawing-a-partially-transparent-gdi-bitmap-to-a-borderless-window-using-updatel?rq=1 which seems like a similar question to yours and might be of help? And thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for the question link, but the answer to it was in fact the one that gave me my initial direction, and although I have moved some code around, I am doing the same things that he's doing. This allows me to draw transparent and semi-transparent pixels (as the OP was aiming to do), but not 100% opaque pixels as well. The closest I've managed to get is through using an alpha component of 254, which - when the window is over a white window - results in RGB(255, 1, 1) being drawn. I have found that one workaround is to call FillRectangle twice, but that's not very nice...